# Automatically restart crawler after it is terminated by server

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to build a academic paper recommender system that resembles [arxiv-sanity](https://github.com/karpathy/arxiv-sanity-preserver) but uses fancier algorithms. The first step is to request arXiv server and get all the metadata for further processing.

However, the crawler I wrote is often terminated by arXiv server even I set `time.sleep(10)`, where `10` is (I think) a relatively long period of time to hold the crawler. Fortunately, as my crawler depends on the index in URL, I could save the `idx` and rerun the program later. So here is **my question**: how could I automatically rerun my crawler after it has been terminated.

```py
import time
import requests

area = "cat:cs.ML+OR+cat:cs.CV"

for idx in range(0, 10000, 100):
    base_url = "http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?"
    query = "search_query={}&sortBy=lastUpdatedDate&start={}&max_results={}".format(area, idx, 100)

    response = requests.get(base_url + query)
    # do some processing
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: "the crawler I wrote is often terminated by arXiv server" - Wrap your inner for iteration in a `try/except`, an exception could be terminating your loop, not the "arXiv server".

Comment: on Linux you could use `cron` to run periodicall some code which check if your scrip is running and eventually start it again. But on Linux you can also use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)` which was constructed to restart services when they crash.